# Stop deep link navigation from webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, instagram-api

I am showing Instagram user profile in UIWebView. So, in UIWebView there is the button provided by Instagram page "Open in App". Is there any way somehow I can get rid of that button. Or can I stop navigation to App? Main purpose I do this is to make profile view only. Not allowing users to chat. Else I would prefer hooking to app itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get button request url  in this `UIWebViewDelegate` method

1), Set up `UIWebViewDelegate` in you Class.

2), Assign delegate to UiWebView reference like `webView.delegate = self`

3), Implement bellow `UIWebViewDelegate` method in your class.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if request.url?.absoluteString == "open Application url" // OR you can compare url  {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

Hope it will work for you